# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sanitizer') using callback method

Tags: angular

I have the following code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getQueryParams(this.generateSafeUrl);
}

getQueryParams(callback) {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    let analysisId = params['analysisId'] || null;
    callback({ analysisId, domain });
  });
}

generateSafeUrl({ analysisId = null, domain = null }) {
  let url = 'https://my-site.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.html';
  if (analysisId && domain) {
    url = `${url}?analysisId=${analysisId}&domain=${domain}`;
  }
  this.safeSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

I miss the whole thing that if I don't use a callback and do the following, if it works and the error doesn't occur:

```
getQueryParams(callback) {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    let analysisId = params['analysisId'] || null;
    let domain  = params['domain'] || null;
    this.generateSafeUrl({ analysisId, domain });
  });
}
```

I can't understand why the callback produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're passing a function like this:

```
this.getQueryParams(this.generateSafeUrl);
```

its `this` parameter is set to the caller, i.e. `this` will be something else inside `this.generateSafeUrl`.

One correct way of writing this would be:

```
this.getQueryParams(param => this.generateSafeUrl(param));
```

Arrow functions capture `this` and behave more like what you'd expect them to behave.

Alternatively, one could explicitly bind `this` on the function:

```
this.getQueryParams(this.generateSafeUrl.bind(this));
```

There are quite a few answers here that explain function scoping, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485